# Wikitude with Indoor location (IndoorAtlas)

Tags: javascript, android, wikitude, indoor-positioning-system

I set up a Wikitude project, but I replaced the basic Android GPS with IndoorAtlas. It works quite well, the POIs are appearing and the phone is able to detect its location within 5-7m accuracy.

My problem, that the Wikitude POIs are appearing in a different direction. They should be behind me (south east) but they appearing in north-NorthEast. 
I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/browsingpois.html#browsing-pois
No radar and POI background appear, just the text.

Do any of you have any experience with Wikitude POIs with wrong appearing ?

Thanks,
Karoly

Answer (score 0):

Notice that "POIs appearing in wrong direction" issue is either a compass or a location-provider issue.

I recommend you to display location reported by IndoorAtlas (incl. accuracy) in a debug window/div and test on several devices.

Hope that helps